# Given a non-empty array of digits representing a non-negative integer, increment one to the integer (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, increment

Was wondering if someone could explain the code solution to this problem. It's making no sense to me:

Given a non-empty array of digits representing a non-negative integer, increment one to the integer.

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list, and each element in the array contains a single digit.

You may assume the integer does not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

The solution is as follows :

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    let carry = true
    for (let i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (digits[i] === 9 && carry) {
            digits[i] = 0;
            if (i === 0) {
                digits.unshift(1);
                break;
            }
        } else if (carry) {
            digits[i] += 1;
            carry = false;
        }
    }
    return digits;
};
```

I have a few questions about this solution :

1. what is the purpose of the variable carry?
2. why is digits[i] set to 0?
3. why is there an if statement checking for (i===0)? And in turn, why is there a 1 added afterwards?

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: It's implementing the basic way you add two decimal numbers with pencil and paper. Remember how when two digits in the corresponding part of two numbers add up to more than 9? What do you do? You *carry* the 10 to the next column of digits.

Comment: Maybe make up three or four pairs of random 4-digit numbers and add them together (on paper) while thinking about what you're doing.

Comment: Well this is even easier, make up some random 4 digit numbers and add 1 to them.

Comment: @Pointy I see what you're saying. I don't really get the unshift(1) part though. Say with the number 439 - 9 becomes 0 and we add 1 to 3 becoming 440. Unshift inserts the number 1 rather than adding to the digit. I may be getting something wrong here so please call me out!

Comment: `.unshift(1)` just sticks an extra 1 on the front of the result array. When you're just adding one, the carry cannot be any value other than 1, because the only way to "spill over" from one column to the next is to add 1 to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of integers where every element in the array is represents a digit of a number. Say you are given 456, then at index 0 you have 4, at index 1 you have 5 and at index 2 you have 6.

Now, the problem asks you to add 1 to the given number.

Here carry is mathematical carry that is used when you have to add two digits whose sum is greater than 10. By default we have carry as true because you are adding 1 to the number anyway. First you iterate(reverse) through the given digits and look for digits that are equal to 9 (carry being true), then change the current digit to zero and put 1 in the front. If carry is true and and the digit is not 9 then simply add 1 to the digit.

examples :

```
plusOne([4,9,7])
(3) [4, 9, 8]
```

here number 497 is given, and you just add 1 to the last digit.

```
plusOne([1,4,9])
(3) [1, 5, 0]
```

here we see that the last digit is 9, so first we change it to zero then we add 1 to the second last digit.

```
plusOne([9,9,9])
(4) [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

here we see that all the digit are 9, we change all digits to zero and add 1 in the beginning (this is where unshift 1 is used)

Comment: In this constrained case, the sum of two digits will never be greater than 10 because all the digits other than the last in the value `1` are zero. So all it has to worry about is the digit `9`.

Comment: `var plusOne = function(arr) {

    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] === 9){
             arr[i] = 0;
                if (i===0){
                    arr.unshift(1);
                }
        } else if (arr[i] != 9) {
            arr[i]++
        }
        return arr
    }
}`
This is the solution I had come up with. Can you explain why this wouldn't work, or how I could alter it to be correct?

Comment: @NineTails thanks for the examples the unshift makes more sense now